# Flexbox stack height

Tags: css, flexbox, height

[Stack Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kVjL.png)

I want to stack flexbox items and not have the same heights, Almost similiar to `pinterest layout` so the posts don't have any spacing between, If it's possible without [`Masonry`](https://masonry.desandro.com/) it would be the best.

So far i have this

```
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    max-width: 100%;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.flex-content {
    margin: 15px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

They do still stack as the image below, Is it possible in any smart way?

Thanks!

Comment: You want to stack vertically instead of horizontally. Have a look at [flex-direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction).

Comment: Can you consider a solution with css grid?